# Choice of mean: arithmetic, geometric, harmonic?

Tags: mean, geometric-mean

I've followed the discussion stream about different types of means, towards which end I'd like to pose the following query:

I have two columns of biological data tht have been log-transformed (e.g. 1000 -> 3, 100 -> 2), and I've taken the difference between them (e.g. 3 - 2 = 1).  I wish to know the "mean" for the data in the log-transformed difference column.  Which is the (most) correct mean to use in this case, and why: arithmetic, geometric, or harmonic?

Comment: What are you investigating with the log-transformed values? And, relatedly, why are you applying the log transformation in the first place?

Comment: The mean of the logarithms corresponds, naturally, to the geometric mean. You'd need good reason to use anything else.